# Invalid Expression Flag G Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, flags

I am trying to use Jquery to load a partial view on my page but I keep getting this Invalid Expression Flag G error, I have no idea what it means.

Here is the code that I have created in my cshtml file:

```
<script>
    $('#getDetails')
        .click(function() {
            $('#detailsPlace').load(@Url.Action("GetDetails", "Home"));
        });
</script>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="getDetails">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<div id="detailsPlace"></div>
```

This is the code inside my contoller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ReferenceRepository test = new ReferenceRepository();

        var response = test.GetParts("A");
        return View(response);
    }

    public ActionResult GetDetails()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

This is just some dummy code in my PartialView:

```
<body>
    <p>HELLOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
</body>
```

When I look at the web console which is where I found the error and click on it it takes me to this line of code

```
$('#detailsPlace').load(/Home/GetDetails);
```

this is code from the webpage and thats why it looks different to mine. My controller is actually called HomeController but it only expects Home for some reason

Comment: You want a string literal.

Comment: @SLaks thank you I'm not getting any errors now but it still isnt working can  you see anything else wrong with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/Home/GetDetails` is being interpreted as a [**regular expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), using "Home" as the pattern and "GetDetails" as the flags.  That's an invalid regular expression, hence the error.

You should wrap it in quotes, like this::

```
$('#detailsPlace').load('@Url.Action("GetDetails", "Home")');
```

Comment: Thank you that got rid of the rror but the code still isnt loading my partial view can you see anything which would be wrong?

Comment: I may have to see the code on the production site to determine the problem.

Comment: it should work when I just run visual studio shouldnt it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm unfamiliar with Visual Studio.

Comment: Your quote syntax is completely wrong; just wrap it in quotes as a string literal.  The `@Url...` is server-side Razor code.

Comment: @SLaks, I wasn't sure what the preprocessor was, so I didn't know if I could just place quotes around it.  However, I don't understand what's wrong with my syntax.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Well your output from this Razor snippet would be `$('#detailsPlace').load('"' + /Home/GetDetails + '"');`

Comment: Oh!  @LukeRayner, see my update and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @RickHitchcock thats what i though you meant the first time, thats what i put and it doesnt work, I just thought you put the + to should be what you changed ahaha

Comment: Ha, that explains why it fixed your syntax error.  Maybe someone with experience with Razor or Visual Studio can get you going.